# How to set DateTime Field Value without TimeZone in XPages ServerSide JS

Tags: xpages

When I set a value of Date/Time field in XPages It's value is like below.
I would like to set value without TimeZone (in this samples without `ZE3`).

Field Name: dtField1 
Data Type: Time/Date 
**17.11.2016 13:13:31 ZE3**

I tried `@Today()` and these 2 lines code below but I could not be succeded. is there any way to do it?

```
var now:NotesDateTime = session.createDateTime(@Now());
document1.replaceItemValue("dtField1", now);
```

Regard
C.A.

Comment: DateTime containing time value is always with timezone, internally. Handle it when you read/format the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Time zone is always part of NotesDateTime field if field contains date *and* time no matter how you created it.

If the field contains date *only* or time *only* then time zone is omitted.

[image]

Set date only with

```js
var now:NotesDateTime = session.createDateTime(@Now());
now.setAnyTime();
document1.getDocument().replaceItemValue("dtField1", now);
```

and time only with

```js
var now:NotesDateTime = session.createDateTime(@Now());
now.setAnyDate();
document1.getDocument().replaceItemValue("dtField1", now);
```